# $setvalidity not setting errors as conditions specified

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying a simple `angular` date validation where `todate` gives an error message on submit, when selecting date more than current date. But the output is not as expected. It is giving error on selecting any date, but condition is checking properly in debug break points.

plunker link": [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/Ri8oYDkIhA19OwL8WllD/)

Here is the code:

```
$scope.form1submit=function(date){

        var today = new Date();
        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

        if(dd<10) {
            dd='0'+dd
        } 

        if(mm<10) {
            mm='0'+mm
        } 

        todayDate = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
        console.log(todayDate);
        var toDate = date.toDate;
        var toDatelength = date.toDate.length;


        if(toDate > todayDate && toDatelength > 0){

            $scope.form1.todate.$setValidity("todateerror", false);

        }else{
            $scope.form1.todate.$setValidity("todateerror", true);
        }
        };
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-Date-Picker-For-jQuery-AngularJS-Datepicker/"></script>
<span class="">
        <label class="">to date</label>
        <input id="toDate" name="todate" type="text" class="" 
               ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}"
               placeholder="To Date" 
               data-datepicker="{theme: 'flat'}" 
               ng-model="date.toDate" 
               ng-disabled="date.fromdate" 
               ng-required="date.fromdate" />
       <span ng-show="form1.$submitted && form1.todate.$error">

           <div ng-message="todateerror" class="">To date is more than todays date</div>
       </span>
</span>
```

Comment: what is in your model? create a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/)/[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) etc example, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/bWBDn7gnVFyWV7ZdePyD?p=preview) I've fixed your code.

- 1) You shouldn't compare dates as a strings.
- 2) instead of `form1.todate.$error` you have to use `form1.todate.$error.todateerror`

Comment: Thank you so much. But it is able to read from date where giving (NaN)(Not a number) in console. I modified the split as per my date format. But still no luck. On debug, the date is being set properly to toDate variable. But in console, I`m not able to read data. Will dig more and get back.